# JSpinner Number editor

Tags: java, jspinner

What does this below piece of code actually does,

```
 //Make the year be formatted without a thousands separator.
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, "#"));
```

Why this is required for eliminating the comma in JSpinner numberModel.

I am new to java , please explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the `JSpinner.NumberEditor` constructor is the decimal format. You should read [DecimalFormat's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to actually understand how it works, but in this case it's the simplest format `"#"` that just means "all digits go here". Since it doesn't contain any separators, they won't appear in the formatted text. If you wanted them, you'd specify something like `"### ###"` (meaning groups of three digits separated by spaces).

Reading [the official tutorial on formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) is also a good idea. (Thanks to Ilya Lapitan for the comment.)

The default format used by JSpinner depends on the locale settings, which are usually determined by your OS and/or Java settings. To determine the format dynamically you can do something like this

```
if (spinner.getEditor() instanceof JSpinner.NumberEditor) {
    JSpinner.NumberEditor numberEditor = (JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor();
    System.out.println(numberEditor.getFormat().toPattern());
}
```

On my system (Russian OS locale, but US English NetBeans) it prints `#,##0.###`, which means:

- `#,##0`—group digits by three, separate groups by commas and leave at least one digit there (denoted by the last `0` instead of `#`);
- `.###`—round to three digits after the decimal point (which is displayed as `.`).

If the `instanceof` operator evaluates to `false` that means that your spinner is not set up to display numbers or that a customized editor was installed.

Comment: Here is also good tutorial: [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: How can i see what is the default decimal format on the JSpinner.

Comment: When i do a getValue on a spinner with "#" as decimal format it returns with a ".0" like "2016.0".cHow can i get only 2016

Comment: @user3164187, if you plan on using only integer values (for year, it is obviously the right choice), then just create the spinner using an integer model, like `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(2016, 1970, 9999, 1))`.

Comment: Is there a way to getValue from Jspinner with grouping? Like if it is displayed as 2,016 - store the same in a variable with comma

Comment: @user3164187, try `numberEditor.getTextField().getText()`.